# Which metric to use when both positive and negative classes have equal importance

Tags: machine-learning, classification, unbalanced-classes, auc, precision-recall

As far as I see, many classification problems focus on identifying the positive instances and therefore evaluating the performance of the classifier based on this.

I wonder if any specific metric needs to be used if both classes have equal importance. Or, it would not matter?

Considering that I have an imbalanced data, I am planning to use AUC. Would this be a good metric if I care about both classes?

I appreciate any insights!

Comment: Area under ROC, Metthews correlation, Cohens Kappa are the best metrics for giving equal importance to both the classes.

Answer (score 1):

The process of focusing on finding the positive instances and classifying them in the class associated with positive values is analogous to finding negative classes and associate them with class associated with negative values. By finding the observations that belong to positive class is same as finding the classes not belonging to positive class and hence them belonging to the negative class.